# ZK error UI component

Tags: css, exception, zk

i have an error when deploying ZK in apache,

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: neraca.neracaController cannot be cast
 to org.zkoss.zk.ui.util.Composer
    org.zkoss.zk.ui.metainfo.ComponentInfo.toComposer(ComponentInfo.java:410)
    org.zkoss.zk.ui.metainfo.ComponentInfo.toComposer(ComponentInfo.java:397)
    org.zkoss.zk.ui.metainfo.ComponentInfo.toComposers(ComponentInfo.java:365)
    continued...
```

here's my zul file,

```
<?init class="org.zkoss.zkplus.databind.AnnotateDataBinderInit"?>
<zk>
    <style>
    .silvergray .complex-layout,
    .silvergray .complex-layout .z-south,
    .silvergray .complex-layout .z-west {
        background: #C5E6EF; 
    } 
    .breeze .complex-layout,
    .breeze .complex-layout .z-south,
    .breeze .complex-layout .z-west {
        background: #F7F7F7; 
    } 
    </style>
    <style>
        .z-borderlayout { 
            background: #FFFFFF 
        } 
        .complex-layout .z-north { 
            background: #008BB6; 
        }
        img.complex-layout-header-img {
            padding: 0 10px; 
        } 
        .complex-layout-header-label { 
            position: relative; 
            top: -30px; 
            padding-left: 40px; 
            font-size: 24px; 
            color: White; 
            font-weight: bold; 
        } 
        .inner-border, 
        .inner-border .z-north, 
        .inner-border .z-west,
        .inner-border .z-south, 
        .inner-border .z-east { 
            background: #FFFFFF; 
        }
        .dl-link {
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

    </style>
    <borderlayout sclass="complex-layout" height="700px">
        <north size="90px" border="0">
            <div>
                <image sclass="complex-layout-header-img" src="/images/Adempiere.png" />
                <label sclass="complex-layout-header-label" value="SCM for Small and Medium Business" />
            </div>
        </north>
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <west width="200px" border="0" flex="true" splittable="true" margins="0,5,0,0">
            <vlayout spacing="0">
                <panel width="100%" border="normal" title="Menu">
                    <panelchildren style="padding:5px;">
                        <vbox>
                            <toolbarbutton label="Jurnal Keuangan" href="lap_keuangan.zul" image="images/book.png"/>
                            <toolbarbutton label="Buku Besar " href="neraca.zul" image="images/3.png"/>
                            <toolbarbutton label="Rasio Lancar" href="rasiolancar.zul" image="images/Modify.png" />
                            <toolbarbutton label="Rasio Kas" href="kas.zul" image="images/2.png"/>
                            <toolbarbutton label="Rasio Cepat" href="cepat.zul" image="images/Pie.png"/>
                            <toolbarbutton label="Rasio Modal Kerja dan Aktiva" href="aktiva.zul" image="images/Bar.png"/>
                        </vbox>
                    </panelchildren>
                </panel>

            </vlayout>
        </west>

        <!-- Content -->
        <center>
            <borderlayout sclass="inner-border">
                <north border="0" height="4%" margins="2,3,0,0">
                    <label value="Neraca Keuangan" style="font-size:20px;" />
                </north>
                <center border="0" margins="0,3,3,3">
                    <window id="win2" title="" width="auto" height="auto" border="" apply="neraca.neracaController">
                        <grid>
                            <rows>
                                <row>
                                    <hlayout>
                                        <div>
                                            <label>Tahun</label>
                                            <combobox id="tahun" >
                                                <comboitem label="2002"/>
                                                <comboitem label="2003"/>
                                                <comboitem label="2004"/>
                                                <comboitem label="2005"/>
                                                <comboitem label="2006"/>
                                            </combobox>
                                            <button id="pilih" label="pilih"/>
                                            <button id="cetak" label="Cetak" image="images/Print.png"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </hlayout>
                                </row>
                            </rows>
                        </grid>
                        <listbox id="neraca" multiple="true"  model="@{win2$composer.allEvents, load-after='pilih.onClick'}">
                            <listhead>
                                <listheader label="Nomer Transaksi"/>
                                <listheader label="Akun"/>
                                <listheader label="Periode"/>
                                <listheader label="Saldo Awal"/>
                                <listheader label="Debet"/>
                                <listheader label="Credit"/>
                            </listhead>
                            <listitem self="@{each='event'}" value="@{event}">
                                <listcell label="@{event.trans_no}"/>
                                <listcell label="@{event.acc_number}"/>
                                <listcell label="@{event.periode}"/>
                                <listcell label="@{event.saldo}"/>
                                <listcell label="@{event.debet}"/>
                                <listcell label="@{event.credit}"/>
                            </listitem>
                        </listbox>
                    </window>
                </center>
            </borderlayout>
        </center>
        <south size="40px" border="0" style="background: none repeat scroll 0 0 ;">
            <toolbar mold="panel" align="center">
                            Powered by ZK 
            </toolbar>
        </south>
    </borderlayout>
</zk>
```

i guess error in apply tag, but im not sure, i have changed it but error still occured, please anyone help me :)

Answer (score 1):

What does your java class neraca.neracaController look like? It must extend from GenericForwardComposer. If it does then there should be no problems.

```
public class NeracaController extends GenericForwardComposer {
    ...
}
```

For more information please refer to [this documentation](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Essentials/Displaying%20Information%20in%20a%20Grid%20Using%20Data%20Binding/Implementing%20Data%20Binding).